# click to Zoom inserted image on canvas clip it, snippet jquery, html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm programming a canvas image to be able to zoom in/out after the control button is clicked.

The red ball normal size is `128x128px`. when Zooming in too much...the image is clipped by its own container...how do I fix this?

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gvq7m/27/

This is what I've tried...
I want the zoom in to be correct without clipped image...

```js
let M_GlassesZoom=1; 
let L_GlassesZoom=1;


$('.ZoomGlasses').on("click",function(event) {

 if($(this).hasClass("ZoomGlassesPlus")){
    M_GlassesZoom+=0.5; 
 }
 else if($(this).hasClass("ZoomGlassesLess")){
    L_GlassesZoom+=0.5;
 } 

  drawMe();

});
  


 var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // core drawing function
 var drawMe = function() { 
  var ImgGlasses = document.getElementById('glasses');
  canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

 var GlassesWidth=128;
   var GlassesHeight=128;


   if(M_GlassesZoom!=1){
    
    GlassesWidth=GlassesWidth/M_GlassesZoom;
    GlassesHeight=GlassesHeight/M_GlassesZoom;
    
   }
   
   if(L_GlassesZoom!=1){
    
    GlassesWidth=GlassesWidth*L_GlassesZoom;
    GlassesHeight=GlassesHeight*L_GlassesZoom;
    
   }
   
 
   ctx.drawImage(ImgGlasses, 0, 0, GlassesWidth, GlassesHeight, 50, 50, 128,128);
 

  
  
  
  
  }
  
  
  drawMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ZoomGlasses ZoomGlassesPlus">zoom +</button>
<button class="ZoomGlasses ZoomGlassesLess">zoom -</button><br/>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Japan_small_icon.png" style="height:70px;width:70px;opacity:0" height=70 width=70 id="glasses" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the destination width/height fixed to 128px so when the ball gets bigger than that it will get clipped. Naturally, the source width and height should be fixed and the destination calculated.

```js
let M_GlassesZoom=1; 
let L_GlassesZoom=1;


$('.ZoomGlasses').on("click",function(event) {

 if($(this).hasClass("ZoomGlassesPlus")){
    M_GlassesZoom+=0.5; 
 }
 else if($(this).hasClass("ZoomGlassesLess")){
    L_GlassesZoom+=0.5;
 } 

  drawMe();

});
  


 var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 // core drawing function
 var drawMe = function() { 
  var ImgGlasses = document.getElementById('glasses');
  canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

 var GlassesWidth=128;
   var GlassesHeight=128;


   if(M_GlassesZoom!=1){
    
    GlassesWidth=GlassesWidth/M_GlassesZoom;
    GlassesHeight=GlassesHeight/M_GlassesZoom;
    
   }
   
   if(L_GlassesZoom!=1){
    
    GlassesWidth=GlassesWidth*L_GlassesZoom;
    GlassesHeight=GlassesHeight*L_GlassesZoom;
    
   }
   
 
   ctx.drawImage(ImgGlasses, 0, 0, 128,128, 50, 50, GlassesWidth, GlassesHeight);
 

  
  
  
  
  }
  
  
  drawMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ZoomGlasses ZoomGlassesPlus">zoom +</button>
<button class="ZoomGlasses ZoomGlassesLess">zoom -</button><br/>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Japan_small_icon.png" style="height:70px;width:70px;opacity:0" height=70 width=70 id="glasses" />
```